# date() expects parameter 2 to be integer, string given - Help Me

Tags: php, laravel, date

My Laravel 5.2 code is

```
$this->timestamp=date('Y-m-d',intval($timestamp));
$datetime=date('Y/m/d', $timestamp);
```

> ***date() expects parameter 2 to be integer, string given***

That error occur. But that error show when choose the day 31, not on other days (1 to 30). The other days are ok.

When I change my code like that

```
$this->timestamp=date('Y-m-d',intval($timestamp));
$datetime=date('Y/m/d', intval($timestamp));
```

Error solved but the date show is not correct. The date always show ***1970/01/01***
Please help me, how to fix this?

Comment: What do you get if you do `var_dump($timestamp)`?

Comment: As steve said, if we would assume `$timestamp` is a unix timestamp, this code would work. It however does not, no definite answer can be given. You want us to solve a question without knowing the details?

Comment: The detail is - In my Laravel project there is calendar (Date picker) on the right sidebar and when you click on the date, it's search and show the posts which are posted on that date. In my case, on other dates (1 - 30) is working well but when click on the date 31, it show like that error. 
**date() expects parameter 2 to be integer, string given**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using Laravel, you can do this with Carbon:

```
Carbon::parse($timestamp)->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 5):

try

```
$timestamp=date('Y-m-d',"1478774037");
echo $timestamp;
```

or

```
$timestamp=date('Y-m-d',strtotime("31-07-2016"));
echo $timestamp;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try typecasting:

```
$this->timestamp=date('Y-m-d',((int)$timestamp));
$datetime=date('Y/m/d', ((int)$timestamp));
```